# How to layout UI app android like facebook?

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I saw some same topic here but can not find the anwser so I create my ask question. 
I am a newbie in android and I am learning to build a layout by my self, I see facebook app and wonder how they layout UI with friend list behind main content. And when you click toggle friends main content will slide to left side and friends list show up.I try to use navigation drawer and viewpager but can not achive. I wrong something or it must use by other technique. Anyone can give some idea how to do that.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After two days, finally i found the answer by use a great this SlidingMenu.
https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Comment: I'd be really careful with that framework, it hasn't been updated in 3 or 4 years, so not sure how compatible it will be with everything thing. Ultimately, it's just one view behind another.

Comment: you right, i just try to use it in android studio and has some problem.In other side, your what is "view behind another" mean. I don't know how to make it like slide?